# Alembic bulk_insert not addind data to DB

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm working for the first time with alembic and I want to insert data into a table after doing a migration.

This is my code

```
def upgrade():
acl_table = op.create_table('mqtt_acl',
                sa.Column('created_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
                sa.Column('updated_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
                sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
                sa.Column('allow', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
                sa.Column('ipaddr', sa.String(60), nullable=True),
                sa.Column('username', sa.String(100), nullable=True),
                sa.Column('clientid', sa.String(100), nullable=True),
                sa.Column('access', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
                sa.Column('topic', sa.String(100), nullable=True),
                sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name=op.f('pk_mqtt_acl'))
                )
### end Alembic commands ###

op.bulk_insert(acl_table,
              [
               {
                'id': 2,
                'username': "USERNAME",
                'clientid': "CLIENTID",
                'allow': 1,
                'access': 1,
                'topic': '#',
                }
               ]
              )
```

Then I run `alembic upgrade head` and it work's fine, doesn't return any error, but when I query the DB the data wasn't inserted and I can't figure out what's wrong.

I know the code is detected because if a make an invalid bulk_insert it gives me an invalid syntax error.

Can any one help me?

Comment: What exactly do you see when you run `alembic upgrade head`? Have you reverted to previous state before retrying? In other words what does `current` show you, compared to your WIP revision.

Comment: In addition you'd get the syntax error even though you'd moved past the revision in progress, because Alembic has to parse the revision Python modules anyhow, or so I've understood it.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I get this message

`INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.`

Comment: If that's it, then you've probably already run your migration once, and it has erred or you've changed it after. Compare what `alembic current` shows to your revision in progress.

Comment: The `alembic current` returns the same thing. And I don't understand what you mean with " shows to your revision in progress"

Comment: Compare the current revision number against the revision number of the migration file you're working on. If the current revision **is** the same that you're working on, you've already run that migration and changing it has no effect. You have to downgrade to previous revision and re-run if you want your changes to apply. Or create a new revision that has your changes and upgrade to that.

Comment: Ok, got it now :) The numbers are different

Comment: You still might've run it, and just moved ahead. The output you gave indicates that your DB is up to date already, i.e. all migrations have been applied.